# Could not find the Blank Android Wear Application template in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin Studio. I am trying to create an app for Android Wear using Xamarin studio. I have installed the Xamarin Studio 5.5 (upto date version) and Xamarin.Android version 4.18 (Trial Edition). I've gone through the below link before I start to set up my environment.

http://blog.xamarin.com/tips-for-your-first-android-wear-app/

As said in the blog, I have installed the latest Xamarin Studio, in which I couldn't find the template for creating a new Android Wear application in either my XamarinStudio or Visual Studio.

I have tried to download the sample given in the below link:

http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/android/Android%20Wear/

On building the samples, it gives me the dll missing errors. 
for ex: I have downloaded the Eliza Chat sample from the above sample, and on running the sample I have been faced some dll missing issues. After downloading them manually from internet and refer them, I am facing the below error

**"Error    1   No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowSwipeToDismiss'. C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Wearable\1.0.0\embedded.\res\values\values.xml  128 ElizaChat"**

**Note**: I have installed the Android Wear Emulator with the help of the SDK Manager. And I have installed the Android L (API 20, L Preview) and Android 4.4 W(API20) through SDK Manager. And I have installed Android Support Repository and Android Support Library.

Do I need to install any thing else to work with Android Wear application. Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks,

Karuppasamy P

Comment: I have removed a particular line which contains the attr android:windowSwipeToDismiss from the values.xml (just to ensure the Android wear application runs in my environment) and it runs successfully. Still I dont know how can I write a new Android Wear App